# Attempting to create a query that will return all records has me stumped

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with three tables.  "Roster", "Training Courses", and "Course Enrollment"
Roster and Course Enrollment are connected by "ETID" (employee training ID).  Course Enrollment and Training Courses are connected by "Course ID".
I am trying to create a query that will return ALL employees, and a YES/NO value for all courses.
I've written the following to look at specific employees, but I cant seem to find the right way to return all employees. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT [TRAINING COURSES].[course id]
     , [TRAINING COURSES].[course name]
     , "YES" AS Completed
     , [COURSE ENROLLMENT].[training date]
FROM [TRAINING COURSES] 
INNER JOIN [COURSE ENROLLMENT]
            ON [COURSE ENROLLMENT].[course id]=[TRAINING COURSES].[course id]
WHERE [COURSE ENROLLMENT].[ETID]=[ENTER ETID]

UNION ALL 

SELECT [TRAINING COURSES].[course id]
     , [TRAINING COURSES].[course name]
     , "No" AS Completed
     , NULL
FROM [TRAINING COURSES]
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [COURSE ENROLLMENT]
    WHERE [COURSE ENROLLMENT].[course id]=[TRAINING COURSES].[course id] 
    AND [COURSE ENROLLMENT].[ETID]=[ENTER ETID:]
)
ORDER BY [TRAINING COURSES].[course name];
```

Comment: Just a note: your queries will be a lot easier to read and write if you use Pascal case: `CourseEnrollment` instead of `[COURSE ENROLLMENT]`.  You may prefer underscores (`Course_Enrollment`), but frankly anything's better than bracketing every table and every field.

Comment: One of the greatest evils of Access, IMHO, is that it allows spaces in object names. And I'm not a reflexive Access-basher....

Comment: I'm a full-time Access developer and I haven't used spaces in object names since my first few years of working with it. It just becomes obvious after a very short time that there is no utility there. Many people confuse object names with presentation-level names, most of which can be defined in your object definitions (like the caption property of a field in a table).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use Union in this query. Replace the INNER JOIN with a LEFT OUTER JOIN and it will accomplish the same as your query but will perform better.

```
SELECT [Training Courses].[Course Id], [Training Courses].[Course Name], 
        IIF(IsNull([Course Enrollment].[ETID]), "NO", "YES") as Completed,
        [Course Enrollment].[Training Date]
FROM    [Training Courses]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Course Enrollment]
            ON [Training Courses].[Course Id] = [Course Enrollment].[Course Id] 
ORDER BY [Training Courses].[Course Name]
```

If you want all employees and all courses, you'll need to do a cross join between the Roster and Training Course table. You would then do a left join with the course enrollment table to get the yes no like above.

Answer (score 0):

Drop `WHERE [COURSE ENROLLMENT].[ETID]=[ENTER ETID]` from both sub-queries.